# custom post type archive template per custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I want to list all posts with a corresponding template for a custom taxonomy term of a custom post type. To make it easier to understand:

The custom post type is called PUBLICATIONS and has a custom taxonomy called LISTS. Each list template is slighty different, so when all posts are listed on the archive-publications page, posts in term LIST A shall be displayed using Template A, LIST B Template B, and so on.

I've tried this:

```
<?php
function publikationen_archive() {
    if ( is_archive('publikationen') && is_tax('downloads') ) { get_template_part( 'templates/content-downloads' );
    } elseif ( is_archive('publikationen') && is_tax('sonderbaende-kataloge') ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-sonderbaende-kataloge' );
    } elseif ( is_archive('publikationen') && is_tax('neuerscheinungen') ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-neuerscheinungen' );
    } elseif ( is_archive('publikationen') && is_tax('untersuchungen') ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-untersuchungen' );
    } elseif ( is_archive('publikationen') && is_tax('studien-materialien') ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-studien-materialien' );
    }
} ?>
```

which didn't work. Then I came across the filter `single_template`, `template_redirect` and `template_include` but don't really know what to do with them.

Comment: `is_post_type_archive` is for checking if the view is a custom post type archive. `has_term` is for checking if a post has a particular taxonomy term.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. :-)

Comment: done, as suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it.**

SOLUTION:

```
<?php 
if ( has_term( 'downloads', 'listen', $post->ID ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-downloads-vergriffener-baende' ); 
} 
elseif ( has_term( 'untersuchungen', 'listen', $post->ID ) ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-untersuchungen' ); 
} 
elseif ( has_term( 'studien-materialien', 'listen', $post->ID ) ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-studien-materialien' ); 
} 
elseif ( has_term( 'sonderbaende-kataloge', 'listen', $post->ID ) ) { 
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-sonderbaende-kataloge' ); 
}
?>
```

This post: http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/2038 has been greatly helpful in the process.

Comment: Of course you are right. Forgot to mention that the loop is in another template-part:

Answer (score 0):

in your post loop.
use this code.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $post_type = get_post_type(get_the_ID());
            if($post_type !='post'){
                get_template_part('content-' . $post_type, get_post_format());
            }
            else {
               get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            }
            //If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    // if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    //  comments_template( '', true );
                    // }
                //endwhile; ?>
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

then create content-publication.php for your post type page structure.

Comment: Of course you are right. Forgot to mention that the loop is in another template-part.